# Matlab get an average plot out of several plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm just getting started with matlab and I'm trying to plot some graph with it.

The problem is I don't know how to get the average data out of 10 plot().
Can anyone guide me for it? Thank you :)
[image]

Comment: Do you have access to the data vectors you used for generating the plots?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't have access to the original data you used for doing the plots:

```
plot_data = get(get(gca,'Children'),'YData'); % cell array of all "y" data of plots
average = mean(cell2mat(plot_data));
```

In order for this to work, you have to use this code right after doing the plots, that is, without plotting to any other figure (`gca` is a handle to the current axes).

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have the original data where in plot(a,b), a and b are an array of values. The rest of the plot such as plot(c,d), plot(e,d).. does not have the same size or incremental value with plot(a,b).   I hope that I put it in a proper sentence...

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to get a single plot() that average all of the 10 plot()

Comment: If the "x" values `a`, `c`, `e` are different, how do you define the average?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fx_files/27134/1/Screen_shot_2010_03_31_at_9.06.25_PM.png

I found out this, but I don't really understand how it works

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27134-plot-average-line/content/plotAverage/plotAverage.m

Answer (score 0):

Assume your data is stored row-wise in a m x n matrix `A`, with n columns corresponding to different values of the continuous error, and m rows corresponding to different curves. Then to inspect the mean over the curves just use

```
Amean = mean(A,1);
plot(Amean)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this link: it solve my problem getting the average plot.
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27134-plot-average-line
After downloading the files just put those script on your working folder and add this line to your script.

```
plotAverage(gca,[],'userobustmean',0)
```